# Javascript: How can I set the cursor during a drag & drop operation on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am developing a Chrome browser extension that allows a drag & drop kind of operation everywhere on the page. However, while the user performs this operation the cursor is usually changed to the text cursor.

How can I alter that behaviour? The CSS cursor property seems to only kick in when you're not holding the mouse button down.

PS: Since, I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome, other browser do not matter to me.

Comment: You'll have to provide more information on what you're doing and how you're doing it.  In my experience, the CSS cursor property looks exactly the same regardless of mouse-button state.

Comment: @Sparky: At least in Chrome, when you hold down the primary mouse button and "drag", the cursor turns into the "I-beam". I think @eWolf wants to override this convention.

Comment: @Jeremy That's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Simply override the "dragstart" message handler as well as the "selectstart"...
While in the function cancel the event...

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
window.addEventListener("dragstart", function(fEventObject){ CancelEvent(fEventObject); } );
window.addEventListener("selectstart", function(fEventObject){ CancelEvent(fEventObject); } );

function CancelEvent(fEventObject) 
{
   if (fEventObject.preventDefault) fEventObject.preventDefault();
   if (fEventObject.cancel != null) fEventObject.cancel = true;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Interesting answer! Do you know if it is also possible to cancel the event after it has been started? I'd like to leave drag & drop and selection on the page untouched until my extension is activated, which happens by holding down the mouse for half a second without moving.

Answer (score 2):

Could you add a css class to the body tag, that sets the cursor, then remove than class on drop?

Comment: Risky. If drop operation won't go as expected (outside the window,bug or something else) then cursor will just stay there.