# How to change the cursor icon when dragging in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to set the icon for cursor when a user is dragging DIV (red div in the following example).

I have tried several attempt, including using CSS `cursor:move` and  `event.dataTransfer.dropEffect` with no success, as the icon always show up a "crossed circle".

Any ideas how to solve this issue using HTML5 drag-and-drop API?

http://jsbin.com/hifidunuqa/1/

```
 <script>
        window.app = {
            config: {
                canDrag: false,
                cursorOffsetX: null,
                cursorOffsetY: null
            },
            reset: function () {
                this.config.cursorOffsetX = null;
                this.config.cursorOffsetY = null;
            },
            start: function () {
                document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
                    console.log('+++++++++++++ dragstart')
                    this.config.cursorOffsetX = event.offsetX;
                    this.config.cursorOffsetY = event.offsetY;
                    this.adjustPostion(event);
                    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
                    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
                }.bind(this));
                document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('drag', function (event) {
                    console.log('+++++++++++++ drag')
                    this.adjustPostion(event);
                }.bind(this));
                document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('dragend', function (event) {
                    console.log('+++++++++++++ dragend')
                    this.reset();
                }.bind(this));;
            },
            adjustPostion: function (event) {
                if (event.pageX <= 0 || event.pageY <= 0) {
                    console.log('skipped');
                    return;
                }
                var elm = document.getElementById('target');
                elm.style.left = (event.pageX - this.config.cursorOffsetX) + 'px';
                elm.style.top = (event.pageY - this.config.cursorOffsetY) + 'px';
                console.log(event.pageX);
                console.log(event.pageY);
            }

        };
    </script>
```

Comment: what about mousedown event?

Comment: yes jquery solutions are also ok. thanks

Comment: why not just add a class on drag start and remove it on drag end?

Comment: @Pete Will that work? The element already has a `cursor: move !important;` style on it *all the time*. It doesn't seem likely that adding such a style at drag-time only will change the behavior.

Comment: Is this any use? http://jsfiddle.net/vL6htL5m/

Comment: @lharby Your example does not use the HTML5 drag-and-drop API, which is the source of this particular problem.

Comment: @apsillers correct I need to make it work with HTML5 drag-and-drop API. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: @apsillers good point, I wrote that based on the above code, it's one of the reasons why adding the mcve in the question itself is always good

Comment: @GibboK [this may help you](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) - see the dragging properties section. It shows you can add your own icon whilst dragging, but it seems to go along with the no-entry circle (which may be compulsory as it shows you are not allowed to drop your object where you are)

Comment: Tried :active? Essentially, that's it.

Comment: You could just check if this works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119514/html5-drag-drop-change-icon-cursor-while-dragging

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use mousedown and mousemove

```js
window.app = {
  dragging: false,
  config: {
    canDrag: false,
    cursorOffsetX: null,
    cursorOffsetY: null
  },
  reset: function () {
    this.config.cursorOffsetX = null;
    this.config.cursorOffsetY = null;
  },
  start: function () {
    document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
      console.log('+++++++++++++ dragstart');
      this.dragging = true;
      this.config.cursorOffsetX = event.offsetX;
      this.config.cursorOffsetY = event.offsetY;
      this.adjustPostion(event);
    }.bind(this));
    document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
      if (this.dragging) {
        console.log('+++++++++++++ drag');
        event.target.style.cursor = 'move'; 
        this.adjustPostion(event);
      }
    }.bind(this));
    document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
      console.log('+++++++++++++ dragend');
      this.dragging = false;
      event.target.style.cursor = 'pointer'; 
      this.reset();
    }.bind(this));
  },
  adjustPostion: function (event) {
    if (event.clientX <= 0 || event.clientY <= 0) {
      console.log('skipped');
      return;
    }
    var elm = document.getElementById('target');
    elm.style.left = (event.clientX - this.config.cursorOffsetX) + 'px';
    elm.style.top = (event.clientY - this.config.cursorOffsetY) + 'px';
    console.log(event.pageX);
    console.log(event.pageY);
  }

};
```

```css
#target {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: red;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        #ui1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 50px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: blue;
            z-index: 100;
        }

        #ui2 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 550px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: green;
            z-index: 100;
        }
```

```html
<!-- simulate -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body onload="window.app.start();">
    <div id="ui1"></div>
    <div id="ui2"></div>
    <div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need to control cursor offsets? The example ran perfectly, couldn't replicate in my app though, don't know why.

Comment: to make sure the element does not jump because when you clicked the element you clicked it inside the element, and you need that cursor position offset inside the element.

Answer (score 6):

Do you actually *need* the `Drag` API? I found that I was using the `Drag` API because I was having trouble with the reliability of mouse events (`mouseups` not being captured, for example).

The `Drag` API is only for drag-and-drop functionality, and, if you're simply fiddling with the reliability of your clicking and pointing events, a new API, `.setPointerCapture` is made to handle these cases more effectively. Here's the minimal viable way to achieve this:

```
el.onpointerdown = ev => {
    el.onpointermove = pointerMove 
    el.setPointerCapture(ev.pointerId)
}

pointerMove = ev => {
    console.log('Dragged!')
}

el.onpointerUp = ev => {
    el.onpointermove = null
    el.releasePointerCapture(ev.pointerId)
}
```

Beautifully, you will maintain full control over your cursor's display style.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Indeed a beautiful solution.

Comment: Excellent suggestion

Comment: But you can't set the cursor with this solution either. Just saying ...

Answer (score 3):

I didn't care about a particular cursor, I just wanted to get rid of the "crossed circle" one. My solution was to include **dragover** event (with following function) to all elements, that already had dragenter, dragstart and dragend events.

```
function dragover(event)
{
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `event.dataTransfer.setData();` should solve the problem. Once the element is recognized as draggable the browser will add a move cursor automatically once you drag. Of course, you will have to remove all other `cursor: move` declarations to see the cursor changing while dragging.

Minimal example:

```
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData( 'text/plain', '' );
}.bind(this));
```

If you still want to change the icon (e.g. to use a custom drag icon), you could access the element style using `event.target.style.cursor`.

For more info see [MDN Drag & Drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_and_drop) and [MDN Recommended Drag Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Recommended_Drag_Types)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that does not work. using event.target.style.cursor='none'; does not change the cursor. Could you please apply your solution to my jsfiddle and send me the link? Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I am not exactly sure anymore what you are trying to do. If your goal is to change/remove the icon during drag, I don't know if this is possible. It seems CSS changes only affect elements, that are not dragged. There are a few pointers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079346/javascript-how-can-i-set-the-cursor-during-a-drag-drop-operation-on-a-website

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations

Comment: Correct, I need to change the icon during dragging using HTML5 drag-and-drop API. Thanks for your time on this.